# Render to texture array with Direct3D example

Tags: directx, direct3d

I have searched the net for a good example on this subject, to no avail. Hence, I ask the Stackoverflow community. If there are any examples on rendering to a texture array with Direct3D. This preferably by selecting layers to render to with the geometry shader. Both depth and color should be possible to render.

Comment: A texture array is a texture type, similar to a 3D texture. The difference is that, when sampling, no interpolation between the layers is possible. Texture arrays are available both in DirectX and OpenGL. I asked the question, because it is hard to find info on using this texture type as a rendertarget.

Comment: OK.  I see.  They are only supported in DirectX 10.  Earlier versions only have volume textures.  You can render target a 3D texture in DirectX 10 no prob, and you shouldn't be needing interpolation because you are *writing* to it.  Why can't you write to a 3D texture, and then break it apart to form your texture array?